# CSS - text-overflow not workin in IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I'm using the following css to make text truncate when too long. The layout uses flex and it works perfectly on Chrome, But on IE10 the 3 dots (...) are not displayed, and the text is simply cut.

```
.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: normal
}
```

When I open the developer console in IE10 and look at the css that is getting applied to the element, I don't see 'text-overflow' property. Even when I add it manually it's not getting applied on the element, it's like IE10 doesn't recognize this property!

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe try removing the word-wrap property (or setting it to initial)

Comment: AFAIK 'initial' is not supported in IE. I added it because it was suggested in another stackoverflow thread :)

Comment: Ok what about using -ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: Tried that as well. IE just ignores it and doesn't display it as an attribute :/

Comment: there should be a problem with truncation. do u have your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: what about this https://jsfiddle.net/ts8sn60j/2/

Comment: Questions seeking help with "why isn't this code working?" must include the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

According to caniuse.com, `text-overflow` property is only supported on **IE11**.

Ref: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow